# How to build and package two jar's with different versions having same groupId and artifactId under maven pom.xml

Tags: maven

How to build and package two jar's with different versions having same `groupId` and `artifactId` under maven `pom.xml`.

Basically I need to package both the version jar file under my war file lib directory.
Assuming both versions have different packages and class names i.e no class naming conflict issue.

Eg:

```
<dependencies>    
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
      <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
     <version>6.0.0.Final</version>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: What is the point of this? Do you want two similar packages with different version numbers?

Comment: yes, basically there are two different versions of same code which performs the same but needs to be executed in two different versions.

Answer (score 0):

yeah its Possible the thing needed is just add some rules in pom.xml as that looks similar to this:

```
<executions>
          <execution>
            <id>pack-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>pack-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <!-- configure the plugin here -->
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
```

I Hope this will help you at least up to the level

Comment: Execution of WHAT plugin? And i doubt that Maven will treat two versios of the same artifact the way you think...

Comment: I think No, because what ever the artifact we declare in the pom file will be of different folder of version as mentioned above in the question so, it treats of different version of same artifact thats it but some typical

Comment: @santhosh, Did u mean that I need to specify the <sources>       <source>Some file system dir path</source>
</sources>
under       </configuration> to package both the version jar files

Comment: Having two versions of the same artifact in the dependency tree, Maven will resolve that to only one dependency (and issue a warning).

Comment: @GyroGearless, Ya I agree that maven will pick one with the higher version, but I am looking out for some solution where I can build and package using both the versions.